# PHP/MySQL - store default text in database or in a file?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, default

OK so I am creating a system where whenever a shop signs up, they get 10 default slides that they can then customize later.  The default slide data is just a starting point for them.  But I have to assume a lot of shops will not log in and update the information, they just want something up ASAP.

So say for the Dashboard slide, every shop starts out with the same heading and text until they go in and update it themselves.  Do I insert it in the database, like so:

```
id | slide_id | user_id | headline | text
1  | 1        | 1000    | ...      | ....
2  | 1        | 1001    | ...      | ....
```

So the database will contain many duplicates of that headline and text since it is the default.  Is that a good idea?

Or do I do something like this:

```
define("DEFAULT_TEXT", "The text goes here and just used once in a file.");
$text = ($stmt->num_rows < 1 ? DEFAULT_TEXT : $text);
```

so I have a query that searches through my **slide_data** table to see if anything exists for that slide id, and if it does, then just use that headline and text.. but if there are no rows, which means they have not added anything yet, then just use the constant `DEFAULT_TEXT`.  And that way, I can have different language config files and have translations in there, so if  the language is French then it will use the `DEFAULT_TEXT_FR` constant which will have the manual translation.

---

Which one do you recommend?  I'm not sure if I have the right idea here, so looking for some other opinions and suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the default text outside of the database, storing it in the db creates unecessary duplicate entries which will ultimately effect performance over time (the larger a db table gets the longer it takes to query that table). Once you have it defined just run a query by user id to see if they created text for that slide, otherwise default to your predefined text

Edit:

```
$result = mysql_query(your check to see if slide exists);
while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $displayText = $row['text'];
};

if ($displayText != '') {
    $sql = 'update command';
} else {
    $displayText = DEFAULT_TEXT;
    $sql = 'insert command';
}

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks.  My only concern is that on the backend when they can edit the text, I want to use an inline-edit script.  If it is stored in the database, it's simple - just update the database.  If it's pulling from an outside file, then not sure what to do when someone goes to edit it inline, it will be trying to update the database when nothing is there

Comment: In your backend you have to do an initial query anyway to get the text from the db, if nothing is returned then you can simply display the default text or non at all... also just change your sql query to an insert rather than an update if nothing is returned, then after your conditionals you can just mysql_query($sql); where $sql is created during your check for text

Comment: view my edit, its a rough example of what I'm talking about, obviously you'll want to trigger the insert/update when the user triggers it

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is not necessarily incorrect, but as you hint, you may end up with a large amount of duplicate data.

You may want to consider wrapping these into an object such as ShopSlides which holds default values and configured values by Shop.

This could in a very quick form be something like this:

```
<?php
class ShopSlides{

    protected $slides = array();
    protected $defaults = array(
        '1' => 'Headline',
        '2'=> 'Healine 2'
        ...
    );
    public function __construct($slides){
        $this->slides = $slides;
    }

    public function getSlide($id){
        if(array_key_exists($id,$this->slides)){
            return $this->slides[$id]);
        } elseif(array_key_exists($id,$this->defaults)){
            return $this->defaults[$id]);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the constants solution because you can avoid data redundance and you can easily customize default messages without the need to update a lot of records...

Answer (score 0):

Easy. You just have to parse the admin member shopSlides. That way you will be able to add and manage all your default ShopSlide ! Just add a column "isDefaultShopSlide" to your Table!